# Delete one days total events using an image

Tags: jquery, codeigniter, fullcalendar

Here I am adding an image to day cell using css:

```
.fc-widget-content::after {
     margin-top: 1 px;
    margin-left: 70 px;
    font-family: 'FontAwesome';content:"\f00d";
    position: absolute;
    white-space: pre;
    color:#F00;
}
```

When you click on this icon I want to delete all events on that particular day. I am using `jquery, fullcalendar.js` and I am using day click function as well.

```
dayClick: function(date, jsEvent, view) { 
            alert('Clicked on: ' + date.getDate()+"/"+date.getMonth()+"/"+date.getFullYear());  
        },
```

When I click on day it shows the date, but what I want to achieve is that when you click on that icon I can delete total events on that day. Please help.
Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yo can't do it that way. ::after is not part of the DOM so it's not accesible using Javascript.

In this **[answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5041494/selecting-and-manipulating-css-pseudo-elements-such-as-before-and-after-usin/21709814#21709814)** you could find some methods to fix your problem.